# Sent vs sent to; present vs present to

Tags: grammaticality

> Now I’d like to present you guys, the trailer of the movie.

Vs

> Now I’d like to present **to** you guys, the trailer of the movie.

Also,

> This is the last letter she sent me.

Vs

> This is the last letter she sent **to** me.

Is to required? Or is it not?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous one?

Comment: @Rubioric if possible,try to answer the question..